# Spread types may only be created from object types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I have a simple react-native component using ts that specifies its own styling, however I also want to pass down any styling I might use on it from above the component tree (i.e. somewhere where I am using this component)

```
class RatioImage extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { width, ratio, style, ...props } = this.props;
    return (
      <Image
        {...props}
        style={{
          width: deviceWidth * (width / 100),
          height: deviceWidth * (width / 100) * ratio,
          ...style
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I am currently getting error below on my `...style` not sure why, as its supposed to be an object?

```
[ts] Spread types may only be created from object types.
const style: false | ImageStyle | (number & {
    __registeredStyleBrand: ImageStyle;
}) | RecursiveArray<false | ImageStyle | (number & {
    __registeredStyleBrand: ImageStyle;
}) | null | undefined> | null | undefined
```

Comment: Is `style` an object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an array syntax to supply multiple styles in react native

```
<Image style={[{ width: x, height; y}, style]} />
```

See [the docs for more info](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html)